# Compare and combine two lists of different types using Streams

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
public class Role {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    //getters and setters
}
```

```
public class UserRole {

    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Role role;

    //getters and setters
}
```

```
public class RoleCheckbox {

    private Role role;
    private Boolean checked;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now in my service class I get Lists of Role and UserRole objects. List of Roles contains all available roles, a list of UserRoles contains the roles assigned to the specific user.

I want to compare those two lists and create a list of RoleCheckbox objects.
So newly created list should contain all Roles and "checked" field with value depending on user's roles.

I have resolved that as below:

```
this.roleCheckboxes = new ArrayList<RoleCheckbox>();
for(Role role : roles) {
    Boolean checked = false;
    for (UserRole userRole : user.getUserRoles()) {
        if(userRole.getRole() == role)
            checked = true;
    }
    RoleCheckbox roleCheckbox = new RoleCheckbox(role, checked);
    this.roleCheckboxes.add(roleCheckbox);
}
```

My question is, **how can I do that using Streams?** Or how can I refactor the code to be more readable and friendly?

Comment: Implement `equals` in UserRole, without it won't work

Comment: @azro Why would an `equals` implementation be needed for `==` check?

Comment: @Andreas UserRole has several properties which sould be check, nope ?

Comment: I would suggest you to keep this, since it is more readable.

Comment: @azro Nope, just the `role` field: `userRole.getRole() == role`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent stream can be :

```
this.roleCheckboxes = roles.stream()
        .map(role ->
                new RoleCheckbox(
                        role,
                        user.getUserRoles().stream()
                                .anyMatch(userRole -> userRole.getRole() == role)
                )
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note**

In your code you are using `userRole.getRole() == role` which I think It is wrong because you are comparing between two Objects, and `==` is not correct, I think you mean `userRole.getRole().equals(role)`

Comment: Question code uses `==` identity check. You should probably use that too.

Comment: @Andreas I agree, but the OP compare between two object, which I think it is wrong, in any case, I put a note

Comment: If the objects come from JPA, then the `Role` objects are unified ("interned"), so only one `Role` object will exist for a give role id, making use of `==` valid. Of course, it would likely be safer to use `equals()` if that was implemented to compare `id` only, otherwise you really should use `userRole.getRole().getId().equals(role.getId())`.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to map every `Role` to `RoleCheckbox` with `boolean` parameter depending on existence in `user.getUserRoles()` collection. This can be simplified:

```
// we need to get roles to check first
Set<Role> uRoles = user.getUserRoles().stream()
    .map(UserRole::getRole)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<RoleCheckbox> result = roles.stream()
    .map(role -> new RoleCheckbox(role, uRoles.contains(role))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

P.S.: @Andreas suggests using `IdentityHashMap` if you're checking identity using `==`. I'll leave that as a note, but I would argue if that is the best way. In most cases this is not, what you would like to do.

Comment: A `List<UserRole>` will never contain a `Role`. Question code calls `userRole.getRole()`, your solution doesn't.

Comment: @Andreas of course, I didn't even notice, corrected. Thank you very much

Comment: To be consistent with the `userRole.getRole() == role` check done in the question code, you should probably use an `IdentityHashMap<Role, ?>` for `uRoles`.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure if this is really, what OP is trying to use, but since that's what is in the question, I'll make a remark. Thanks for noticing

Comment: For performance, it would surely be better to use `Set<Role>`, though.

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted answer. The creation of a set of user roles makes the code clearer *and* might perform better. Win-win.